# Sum Data based on Time for weekly,monthly,yearly using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, date, momentjs

I have a JSON js object which I am getting using AJAX.
the problem is I don't have much control on the backend, so the data is coming in simple JS object.

I have a JSON file as follows

```
var test =
[
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 01 2014 05:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 01 2014 09:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 01 2014 02:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 02 2014 06:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 02 2014 09:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 02 2014 04:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 03 2014 02:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 03 2014 01:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 03 2014 10:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 04 2014 7:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 05 2014 10:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
},
{value : 23,
file_date : Wed Jan 06 2014 11:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
}
]
```

the file_ts has different timestamp. my problem is that I have to consolidate this data.

If user select 1 Day then I have to get sum of all data hour wise. If there are 4 values between 2 and 3 hr then I have to sum that data hour wise.

then if weekly then weekly. I am trying to write a nodejs server with express and mysql but its also not working from there.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, this is more a work specification than a question.

Comment: i ahve not been able to implment anything for this. my solution is for something different. this just came up and since backend is not under my control. i am having hard time

Answer (score 0):

Here is what, i'm assuming, you were asking for:

> If a user selects 'January 1st', you want to grab all info where
>   file_date is on the selected date and add up all the hours.

Here are the steps you would need to take:

- Get data from Ajax Call
- Search data by Date (input) and add matches together
- Convert matches to date and add up hours

**NOTE**: I've converted your timezone (IST) to (UTC) so the output will be in GMT

```
// Test data
var test = [{  
    value: 23,
    file_date: "Wed Jan 01 2014 05:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)"
  },{  
    value: 23,
    file_date: "Wed Jan 01 2014 09:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)"
  },{  
    value: 23,
    file_date: "Wed Jan 01 2014 02:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)"
  },{  
    value: 23,
    file_date: "Thu Jan 02 2014 06:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)"
  },{  
    value: 23,
    file_date: "Thu Jan 02 2014 09:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)"
  },{  
    value: 23,
    file_date: "Thu Jan 02 2014 04:34:53 GMT+0530 (IST)"
  }
];

var userInput = 1; // This is the date they typed in

// This function returns all records for a specific day (integer)
var getAllDayData = function(day){
  var response = [];

  for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++){
    var fileDate = new Date(test[i].file_date);
    if(fileDate.getDate() === day){ // getDate gets you day of month
      response.push(fileDate);
    }
  }

  return response;
};

var getTotalHoursFromDates = function(data){
  var totalHours = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    totalHours += data[i].getHours();
  }

  return totalHours;
};

var getTotalHoursFromInput = function(day){
  var dayData = getAllDayData(day);
  var response = getTotalHoursFromDates(dayData);

  return response;
};

// Call the function
var dayTotal = getTotalHoursFromInput(userInput);
console.log(dayTotal); // 58
```

**Regarding your request to grab weekly hours**: You will have to add a function that takes all the days of the week (input), gather all the information for each day, add then add all of those hours together. This is a continuation of the code above.

```
var week = [31,1,2,3,4,5,6]; // This is the days of the selected full week

var getAllWeekData = function(days){
  var response = [];

  for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++){
    var day = getAllDayData(days[i]);
    if(day[0] != null) { // Checks for undefined or null
      for(var y=0;y<day.length;y++){
        response.push(day[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return response;
};

var getAllWeekDays = function(selectedDays){
  var allDays = getAllWeekData(selectedDays);
  var response = getTotalHoursFromDates(allDays);

  return response;
};

var weekTotal = getAllWeekDays(week);
console.log(weekTotal); // 120
```